# Average number of successful picks when drawing marbles

Tags: probability, combinations

Suppose you have a bag with 5 marbles (1 red, 3 green, 1 black). You pick one marble at time without replacement.

If the marble is **red** we call this **successful** pick.

If the marble is **green** you can **keep on picking** from the bag until you pick 3 green marbles (let's say you have 3 lives and 1 green picked => lose 1 life)

If you pick the **black** one, you have to **stop** picking marbles.

How can I know the average number of successful picks? I can calculate the average total picks.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. Feel free to ask if the question is not clear enough.

Thank you

Comment: Possible hint. It might be easier to count the unsuccessful picks. (Suppose there is no red marble at all.)

Comment: Maybe ignore the green marbles and then consider the only case where they actually make a difference: when you pick 3 green marbles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For success you must pick R, GR or GGR. $p(R)=1/5$. $p(GR)=(3/5)(1/4)$ and $p(GGR)=(3/5)(2/4)(1/3)$. So (adding) the total prob of success in a single trial is 9/20. So if you run a large number of trials you expect success about 9 times out of 20.

Comment: Thank you very much, with your explanation i understood my error

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this prpblem is that first I counted all the combinations, so 5!/(3!*1!*1!)=20, then all the combinations that result in fail. First we start when black is the firts marble drawn (Bxxxx) 4!/3!*1!=4, then GBxxx 3!/2!*1!=3, GGBxx 2!/1!*1!=1. At last we have GGGBR, so counting them we get 10/20 or 1/2 chance of failure, which gives us 1/2 chance of wining.I run a matlab code and it also came 1/2

Comment: But the Q says "keep on picking until you pick 3 green marbles". You are continuing to pick AFTER you have picked 3 green marbles.

Comment: oh,you are right, I didnt read that right